# Pandas groupby get filtered sum over total sum

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, True], [1, 4, False], [2, 6, False], [2, 8, True]], columns=["Group", "Value", "C"])

   Group  Value      C
0      1      2   True
1      1      4  False
2      2      6  False
3      2      8   True
```

And I would like for each group to know the sum of values where C equals true over the total sum of values. So for example for group 1 we have 2 / (2+4)

I have managed through some extensive searching to reach the following stage:

```
df.groupby('Group').agg(lambda x: x.loc[x.C == True, 'Value'].sum() / x.Value.sum())

          Value         C
Group                    
1      0.333333  0.333333
2      0.571429  0.571429
```

But (as expected) I get two columns and I would like to get only the one. My ideal result would be:

```
       Ratio        
Group                    
1      0.333333  
2      0.571429
```

I can surely do some modification after the groupby and get what I want, but as I am new to Python I was wondering if I am missing something basic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide by aggregate filtered rows with all rows and then convert Series to one column `DataFrame`:

```
filt = df.loc[df['C']].groupby('Group')['Value'].sum()
tot = df.groupby('Group')['Value'].sum()
df1 = filt.div(tot, fill_value=0).to_frame('ratio')
print (df1)
          ratio
Group          
1      0.333333
2      0.571429
```

Your solution is possible with change `.agg` working with all columns to [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) for return `Series`, but if large data/ many unique groups it should be slow:

```
df = (df.groupby('Group')
        .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.C, 'Value'].sum() / x.Value.sum())
        .to_frame('ratio'))
print (df)
          ratio
Group          
1      0.333333
2      0.571429
```

Solutions working nice also with only `False` group:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, False], [1, 2, True], [1, 4, False], 
                   [2, 6, False], [2, 8, True]], columns=["Group", "Value", "C"])


df1 = (df.groupby('Group')
        .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.C, 'Value'].sum() / x.Value.sum())
        .to_frame('ratio'))
print (df1)
          ratio
Group          
0      0.000000
1      0.333333
2      0.571429

filt = df.loc[df['C']].groupby('Group')['Value'].sum()
tot = df.groupby('Group')['Value'].sum()

print (df1)
          ratio
Group          
0      0.000000
1      0.333333
2      0.571429
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use a division on `groupby.transform()` with sum and assign using `.assign()` after filtering so as to align on ythe index:

```
df[df['C']].assign(Ratio=df['Value']/df.groupby('Group')['Value'].transform('sum'))
```

If more than 1 True per group, use:

```
m=(df.groupby(['Group','C'],as_index=False,sort=False)['Value'].sum()
  .query('C==True').assign(Sum=df.groupby(['Group'])['Value'].transform('sum')))
m[['Group']].assign(Ratio=m['Value']/m['Sum'])
```

---

```
   Group     Ratio
0      1  0.333333
3      2  0.571429
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
result = df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'ratio' : (x.Value * x.C).sum() / x.Value.sum()}))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
          ratio
Group          
1      0.333333
2      0.571429
```